# remove rows from table having full outer join condition

Tags: oracle, join

I have used full outer join condition in my joining query for joining two tables and the sample code is as below

```
  select * from(
   select TO_CHAR(ROUND(col11)) as today1,TO_CHAR(ROUND(col12)) as today2 from T1
   full outer join 
   select TO_CHAR(ROUND(col21)) as yes1,TO_CHAR(ROUND(col22)) as yes2 from T2
  ) MAIN
   where MAIN.today1<>0 and MAIN.today2<>0 and MAIN.yes1<>0 and MAIN.yes2<>0
```

sample output expected as below

```
  today1         today2         yes1            yes2
  somevalue     somevalue      null             null
   null          null            some value       somevalue
  somevalue     somevalue       somevalue        some value
     0                0               0                0
```

I  am trying to **remove rows having all zero** **values** using above where clause but output doubles and also row with zero values apperas. Can I know where I am going wrong. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: How do you expect the last row in your example, when you require all values to be nonzero in your where clause? Or when you are trying to remove rows having all zero values? Aside from the fact that your where clause removes all rows with even one zero value, let alone all zero values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> trying to remove rows having all zero values

use:

```
AND NOT ( MAIN.today1=0 and MAIN.today2=0 and MAIN.yes1=0 and MAIN.yes2=0 )
```

which can be transformed, using De Morgan's laws: 
===> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws 
into:

```
AND ( NOT MAIN.today1=0 OR NOT MAIN.today2=0 OR NOT MAIN.yes1=0 OR NOT MAIN.yes2=0 )
```

which can be further simplified to:

```
AND ( MAIN.today1<>0 OR MAIN.today2<>0 OR  MAIN.yes1<>0 OR MAIN.yes2<>0 )
```

---

Note: if you want to also get NULL values, you must use `IS NULL` operator:

```
where ( MAIN.today1<>0 OR MAIN.today1 IS NULL )
  and ( MAIN.today2<>0 OR MAIN.today2 IS NULL )
  and ( MAIN.yes1<>0 OR MAIN.yes1 IS NULL )
  and ( MAIN.yes2<>0 OR MAIN.yes2 IS NULL )
```

Comment: AND ( NOT MAIN.today1=0 OR NOT MAIN.today2=0 OR NOT MAIN.yes1=0 OR NOT MAIN.yes2=0 )   this solution suited me